# Submit on click in dropdown with Django

Tags: python, html, django, select, onclick

I have a field in my User model in Django specifying the user type.

On all my pages I want a dropdown or select in which I can choose another user type.

I could make links for each user type and change the user type in a new view, e.g. `<a href="/change-user-type/type-1">Change to type 1</a>`, but I've read that such changes should always happen through a post request.

What would be the best approach to this problem? Can I create the links and use

```
<form method="post" action="/change-user-type/">
    <a href="#" class="type-1" onclick="this.submit">Change to user type 1</a>
    <a href="#" class="type-2" onclick="this.submit">Change to user type 2</a>
</form>
```

or can I add a ModelForm to the context data, outputting a `<select>`, automatically appending all possible choices?

I want something like the functionality as when I can choose to use Facebook as a page from the dropdown menu.

Comment: You haven't shown a `<select>` above...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a form for this at all. Just use actual links...

```
<a href="/change-user-type/type-1" class="type-1">Change to user type 1</a>
<a href="/change-user-type/type-2" class="type-2">Change to user type 2</a>
```

Comment: But isn't it bad practice to change database settings through GET requests?

Comment: You're not changing database settings...unless I've misunderstood your question.

Comment: I meant data stored in the database